# Pivoting in T-SQL based on date offset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a table called Orders has three columns:

- OrderID
- UserID
- OrderDate

I need to know, for X months in the past, A users placed 1 order, B users placed 2 orders, C users placed 3 orders, etc.

So the output is a table w/ a MinDate field and then columns for each # of orders from 1 to N, e.g.:

```
declare @t table ( 
  MinDate datetime,
  o_1 int,
  o_2 int,
  o_3 int,
  o_4 int,
  ...
  o_N int
)
```

Each field contains the number of unique customers (UserID's) that placed that many orders between MinDate and the current date. For example, if a row has MinDate = '2009-09-01' then o_6 contains the number of customers who have placed 6 orders between Sept 1 and present, etc.

I have tried several approaches, LEFT JOIN Orders to a number table, etc. but am having trouble getting the correct count of unique users into each column. I could do this easily (and slowly) with a CURSOR but that seems like cheating.

Any suggestions? Let me know if my explanation does not make sense...

Comment: yes, I know how to use PIVOT but not to handle this type of query

Comment: Could you provide the actual query?

Comment: It sounds to me more a OLAP query than OLTP

Comment: actual query? that's the point of the question... I need help writing the query

and yes, I could use MDX to write the query but (a) I would still have the same in-row calculation issues and (b) I am required to do this in SQL

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Pivot2Columns.aspx?display=Print

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stab at it; the part where it breaks down for me is the dynamic pivoting (in other words, you could have an infinite range of orders 1-N).  However, it may point you (or someone else) in the general direction.

```
DECLARE @Orders TABLE
    (
      OrderID INT ,
      UserID INT ,
      OrderDate SMALLDATETIME
    )

INSERT  INTO @Orders
        ( OrderID, UserID, OrderDate )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, '20090102' ),
        ( 2, 1, '20090102' ),
        ( 3, 2, '20090102' ),
        ( 4, 2, '20090102' ),
        ( 5, 2, '20090102' ),
        ( 6, 3, '20090102' ),
        ( 7, 4, '20090102' )

SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    UserID ,
                    COUNT(OrderID) AS CountOrders
          FROM      @Orders o
          WHERE     OrderDate > '20090101'
          GROUP BY  UserID
        ) x PIVOT ( COUNT(UserID) FOR CountOrders IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4] ) ) AS p
```

Comment: Yes, I'm not even worried about the 1-N dynamic PIVOT. I know that requires dynamic SQL so if it makes the problem easier, assume a finite range 1-10 orders. 

The hard part is that a user cannot be double-counted within a row but will surely be double-counted in different rows. For example, assume a customer has placed three orders in Jul, Aug and Sep 2009. 
Assume the result set has three rows, each with a DATETIME month 2009-07-01, 2009-08-01 and 2009-09-01. For the example customer, he would be included in the "3" column in 2009-07-01, "2" column in 2009-08-01 and "1" column in 2009-09-01.

Comment: Does that make sense? (I ran out of characters to explain)

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't see a way around that unless you need to group by months (which I may have misread your spec).  I thought you needed (after the Pivot) a single row for data since x date showing the number of users placing y amount of orders.  Do you need it broken out by date?  As in z customers within y orders per month?

Comment: can u give a snapshot of how the resu;t table looks like